# Having only one base SCSS @use import in entire React application?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

my question is pretty simple. I like using SCSS in React but I was avoiding variables/mixins etc. because for me it was just nightmare to fix all imports after reconstruction of something (I have one scss file for every component separately).

Than I figure out I can easily make absolute paths in React imports for example:

`import "src/scss/variables"`

Now I am again very excited to learn all good things SCSS can offer.

So my question is if I can create one **global.scss** file and use only this file in whole app when importing styles to different SCSS files. For example global.scss would look like this:

```
@use "variables"
@use "mixins"
@use "functions"

@forward "variables"
@forward "mixins"
@forward "functions"
```

And in **components.scss** I would just import:

```
@use "src/scss/global"


.test {
  background-color: global.$primary-color;
}
```

Another question is if there is any possibility that globals are just imported in **main.jsx** pr **app.jsx** and than already used in all files automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible to have a single file for all your variables, mixins and functions. The example you shared is almost right, but you only need to use `@forward` and not `@use`:

```
@forward "variables";
@forward "mixins";
@forward "functions";
```

And make sure these three files are [partials](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4).

Importing this `global.scss` file in the `.jsx` is useless, since it doesn't contain any styles. However, what you can do is to configure your bundler to import it automatically into all of your `.scss` files.

For example, if you use **webpack** and [`sass-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/), you can use the option [`additionalData`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#additionaldata):

```
options: {
  additionalData: "@use \"src/scss/global\";"
}
```

If you get an error about `@import loop`, you need to exclude the global style files so they don't get the automatic import:

```
options: {
  additionalData: (content, loaderContext) => {
    const { resourcePath, rootContext } = loaderContext;

    // Assuming your global files are in this folder
    const styleGlobalPathRegex = /^src\\scss\\.*/;

    const relativeFilePath = path.relative(rootContext, resourcePath);
    const isAGlobalStyleFile = relativeFilePath.match(styleGlobalPathRegex);

    return isAGlobalStyleFile ? content : "@use \"src/scss/global\";" + content;
  };
}
```

If you use **Vite**, you can add it with [`css.preprocessorOptions`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions):

```
css: {
  preprocessorOptions: {
    scss: {
      additionalData: ...
    }
  }
}
```